# Group form fields in django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-forms

Is there a way in Django to group some fields from a ModelForm? For example, if there's a model with fields like: age, gender, dob, q1, q2, q3 and a form is created based in such Model, can I group the fields like: info_fields = (age, gender, dob) and response_fields = (q1, q2, q3). This would be helpful to display all fields in a more organized way on a template.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django and fieldsets on ModelForm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518966/django-and-fieldsets-on-modelform)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this post, I believe your hinting at using fieldsets in a ModelForm.
[Django and fieldsets on ModelForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518966/django-and-fieldsets-on-modelform)