# Access a subset of django form fields

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

How can one insert markup between subsets of form fields in django, while staying DRY?

Given:

```
class CompensationUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Compensation
    fields = [
        'salary1',
        'salary2',
        'incentive1',
        'incentive2', ]
```

I'd like to be able to access them in the view in such a way that I can wrap groups of them in markup.  For example:

```
<div class="ibox-content">
    {% for field in form.salary_fields %}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<div class="ibox-content">
    {% for field in form.incentive_fields %}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I have over 50 fields on the form in about 10 groups, so I need to do this in a DRY manner.  While I *can* access each field individually, I can't figure out how to define subsets (either in the UpdateView or directly in the template).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`django-betterforms`](https://github.com/fusionbox/django-betterforms), which has [FieldSets](https://django-betterforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basics.html#fieldsets) that you can group your fields in.

In your Meta class on your form, you specify FieldSets of grouped fields:

```
class Meta:
    fieldsets = (
        ('info', {'fields': ('username', 'email')}),
        ('location', {'fields': ('address', ('city', 'state', 'zip'))}),
        ('password', {'password1', 'password2'}),
    )
```

And in the template you can iterate over the FieldSets

```
{% for fieldset in form %}
    <div class="ibox-content">
        {% for field in fieldset %}
            ...
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

You can see more of the [proposed template implementation here](https://github.com/fusionbox/django-betterforms/blob/master/betterforms/templates/betterforms/form_as_fieldsets.html).

Other solutions are [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10367761/10400050) or [django-form-utils](https://pypi.org/project/django-form-utils/) which is a better documented version of my answer. The latter however seems to be unmaintained today, but could work depending on your Django Version.