# Django Add fieldset legend to ModelForm

Tags: python, django

I have a model:

**models.py**

```
class Doc(models.Model):
    series = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="2", blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="2", blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, help_text="3")
    citizenship = models.ManyToManyField(Citizenship, help_text="4")
```

**forms.py**

```
class DocForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Doc
        fields = '__all__'
```

How do i add 2 legends for these fields?
1 for series and number and 1 for name and citizenship?

template

```
{% for field in form %}
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}" class="control-label col-md-3">{{ field.label }}
        {% if field.field.required %}<span class="required"> * </span> {% endif %}
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        {{ field }}
        {% if field.errors %}
            {% for error in field.errors %}
            <span id="{{ field.id_for_label }}-error" class="help-block help-block-error">{{ error }}</span>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: As far as I know there is still no out-of-the box solution for this. You might want to take a look at this older post: [Django and fieldset on modelform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518966/django-and-fieldsets-on-modelform)

Comment: i've tried but i couldn't make it :\ is it possible to use in BetterForm fields = '__all__' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm writing this, maybe others will need it aswell:

This is how i made it:

**forms.py**

```
class DocForm(BetterModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Doc
        fieldsets = [
        ('main',
         {'fields': ['name', 'citizenship'],
          'legend': 'I. PERSONAL DATA'}),

        ('main1',
         {'fields': ['series', 'number'],
          'legend': 'II. PROFESSIONAL IDENTIFICATION'})]
```

template

```
{% for fieldset in form.fieldsets %}
    <fieldset class="{{ fieldset.classes }}">
    {% if fieldset.legend %}
        <legend>{{ fieldset.legend }}</legend>
    {% endif %}
    {% for field in fieldset %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}" class="control-label col-md-3">{{ field.label }}
            {% if field.field.required %}<span class="required"> * </span> {% endif %}
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            {{ field }}
            {% if field.errors %}
                {% for error in field.errors %}
                <span id="{{ field.id_for_label }}-error" class="help-block help-block-error">{{ error }}</span>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </fieldset>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Why there are 2 Meta classes?